# Is it possible to fetch the values from push notification when user clicks on notification ? (App closed state)

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging

below is my current implementation it is working only when app is opened

```
`@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
       if(intent.hasExtra("url")){
           url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
           LoadWebview();
       }else {
           LoadWebview();
       }
    }`
```

Comment: Including part of code where you send intent in your notification would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the push while the app is closed (no running task), the new task is created and `onCreate` of your activity is called, so you can use Intent's extras in the following way:

```
@Override
void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate()
    /// other logic

    if (intent.hasExtra("url")) {
           url = intent.getStringExtra("url");
           LoadWebview();
    } else {
           LoadWebview();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this way in onCreate also but still it is throwing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to fetch values whether your app is opened or not. Just launch the intent with proper flags.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, May I know those exact flags please.